# Have any javascript package to convert pdf with bookmarks in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I want to convert HTML to pdf with Bookmarks in react. But I did not get any package in react js to add option Bookmark. Have any javascript package to convert HTML to pdf with bookmarks in react?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf

Comment: I didn't find any options to bookmark in this package.

Comment: What you want to bookmark any link or something else

Comment: http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-annotations.html#~textWithLink

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/page-thumbnails-bookmarks-pdfs.html

Answer (score 2):

you can check this package:https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit

in GitHub issue: https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/issues/821 , you can see, it is closed.

I also tried to find the same thing, but not succeeded. if you can find any solution, please update .. thanks